# Meaning of counting argument?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

1. Does "counting argument" mean a proof of  some statements by
   counting something?
2. Is "counting argument" same as "double counting"?  Or does it include both double counting and  bijective proof?

I found some relevant Wikipedia articles [Combinatorial  proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof) and [Combinatorial principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles). But not sure the meaning of counting argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Counting argument* isn’t really a well-defined term, but I’d understand it to mean a proof that two expressions are equal by showing that they are two different ways of counting the same thing. Wikipedia calls this [double counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_%28proof_technique%29), which I consider a very poorly chosen name: to me double counting refers to counting some things twice and therefore having to correct the total by subtracting the amount of over-counting. I prefer to call it simply *counting the same thing in two different ways*.

However, I can imagine someone using the term *counting argument* to include bijective proofs as well as proofs by counting the same thing in two ways.

Answer (score 4):

Counting argument can mean counting the same thing in two different ways to give rise to two different expressions that then have to be equal. For example, we have $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.

Double counting can mean counting the same object twice so that one has to subtract to get the correct number. For example, we have $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.

Comment: That's my take on it, though in come contexts (e.g., enumerative combinatorics), double counting can mean proving equality, say a = b, by showing that a and b each represent different ways of counting the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Tim,

Remember, any set of finite size is trivially countable.

Typically a "counting argument" refers to listing elements of a set in a meaningful way to show that the set is the the same size as the natural numbers or not the same size as the natural numbers.

Comment: Not in the combinatorial context, which is what Tim is talking about.