# Prove that there are no idempotent, commutative quasigroups of even order.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs, quasigroups

I'm trying to prove this using a counting argument - [Meaning of counting argument?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227004/meaning-of-counting-argument)

I understand one can proved this for Latin Squares, as done in this post -[Idempotent and commutative Latin squares of even order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150448/idempotent-and-commutative-latin-squares-of-even-order)

And I know a quasigroup is essentially just an unbounded Latin square, however I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Actually Jens' answer in the link you provided on Latin squares shows a simpler proof. So all you need to do is realize that the multiplication table of an idempotent commutative quasigroup is a Latin square.

---

I'm not familiar with quasigroups, but using the definitions, here's my (perhaps cumbersome) approach:

Thinking about the multiplication table of a commutative idempotent quasigroup of order $n$, it is uniquely determined by the elements under the diagonal (or above, if you prefer). If $n$ is even, then $n-1$ can't be divided into two equal whole numbers, and in the $n-1$ columns under the diagonal there is at least one element appearing in over half of those columns (the number of elements below the diagonal is $n(n-1)/2$). By commutativity the same number of elements appearing below the diagonal also appears above, in the same number of columns.[Each time an element appears it must be in a different column, because of uniqueness of solutions]. But then there's an element appearing in at least $2 \times [(n-2)/2 +1] = n$ columns, **in addition to the column containing the element on its diagonal** - and we know that every column and every row should have a certain element only once.

Hopefully I'll think of a neater way to express this.